# Resize and center an image on the screen without knowing dimensions using CSS

Tags: css

I have a web page on which I want to display an image with the following constraints:

- The viewport dimension is unknown
- The image dimension is unknown (user defined)
- The image needs to be resized at the viewport dimension, keeping its ratio
- The image needs to be centered

Is there a CSS only solution to achieve this ?
Otherwise can it be easily done using js ?

Comment: Does the image should be absolutely positioned or not?

Comment: No, I just want it to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution, the problem is that it is using the flexbox display which is unavailable to I.E. users.
But for me it's an acceptable solution since I mostly need a solution working with Chromium. Even if an universally working CSS would be better.

```css
.image-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center; /* normally it's the default value */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/sports"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-conteiner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/sports"></div>
```

Comment: Without testing I think it doesn't work in many cases, for example when displaying an image in "portrait" format on a screen in "landscape" format.

Comment: Wow look at that. Now it shows an image in "portrait" format on a screen in "landscape" format (when you go full screen).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't resize the image to the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

Give the direct parent of the image a `text-align: center` rule.
And set the image `max-width: 100%;` and `max-height: 100%`. The image now is, so called, responsive.

If you resize the window, the image will keep its demensions and scales with the window width.

The `.container` is centered on the page using a `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" title="sample image" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to resize the image vertically if needed.

Comment: @user2223898 it will now resize both horizontal and vertical

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS rule. By applying `object-fit: cover` to the image, you achieve the same effect as when using `background-size: cover;` in a background image: the image will always fit and adapts the dimensions set by yourself. Here's the CSS:

```
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

You can play around it in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/yoXZeq), by changing the image `width` and
`height`.

I hope it hepls!

EDIT:

I added some JS to make sure it adapts to the viewport (no dimensions needed in the CSS).

For the HTML:

```
<img id="home" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">
```

The CSS:

```
img {
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function wholePage() {
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        $('#home').css('height', h);
        $('#home').css('width', w);
    }

    wholePage();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        wholePage();
    });
});
```

Here you can check the new [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/XagOyW/).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the object-fit rule (look at the answer I have posted a few minutes before yours), but I was unable to make it to work without giving fixed dimensions to the container.

Comment: Sure! I added a small piece of JS, it should work now. Check it at this new [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/559d438e28da381ceb60ecf98d758017).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution requires combining JS and the CSS `object-fit:cover` rule. I just created a JS function with two arguments, one for the element in which we wish to insert the image, and another one for the image itself. That way it seems to be more useful and modular than my previous answer.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image_container">
    <img id="img_to_fit" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="">      
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image_container {
  width: /* unknown */;
  height: /* unknown */;
}

#img_to_fit {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function niceFilling( holderElement, picture ) {
        var h = holderElement.css('height');
        var w = holderElement.css('width');
        picture.css('height', h);
        picture.css('width', w);
    }

    niceFilling( $('.image_container') , $('#img_to_fit') );

    $(window).resize(function() {
        niceFilling( $('.image_container') , $('#img_to_fit') );
    });
});
```

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rogersegu/pen/ZJJbNB/). You can try and modify the `width` and the `height` inside the `.image_container` class, and then refresh or resize the window to see the results.